# SQL select all from one table of joint tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am a SQL beginner and I need to figure out this query: I have three tables joined together from which I am counting certain value, like this:

```
SELECT SEATS_MAX-COUNT(BOOKING_ID) 
FROM FLIGHTS 
  INNER JOIN PLANES ON FLIGHTS.PLANE_ID=PLANES.PLANE_ID 
  LEFT JOIN BOOKINGS ON FLIGHTS.FLIGHT_ID=BOOKINGS.FLIGHT_ID 
GROUP BY SEATS_MAX;
```

This returns number of free seats in a flight. But I would like to get all the columns from FLIGHTS (as in `SELECT * FROM FLIGHTS;`) plus the count number. i.e. something like

```
SELECT FLIGHTS.*, SEATS_MAX-COUNT(BOOKING_ID) 
FROM FLIGHTS 
  INNER JOIN PLANES ON FLIGHTS.PLANE_ID=PLANES.PLANE_ID 
  LEFT JOIN BOOKINGS ON FLIGHTS.FLIGHT_ID=BOOKINGS.FLIGHT_ID 
GROUP BY SEATS_MAX;
```

but this doesn't work (invalid user.table.column, table.column or column specification). Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using Oracle db.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the group by you need to have all the column not aggregated.

So you query has to become:

```
      SELECT FLIGHTS.*, 
             SEATS_MAX-COUNT(BOOKING_ID) 
        FROM FLIGHTS 
  INNER JOIN PLANES 
          ON FLIGHTS.PLANE_ID = PLANES.PLANE_ID 
   LEFT JOIN BOOKINGS 
          ON FLIGHTS.FLIGHT_ID = BOOKINGS.FLIGHT_ID 
    GROUP BY FLIGHTS.Column1,
             ...
             FLIGHTS.ColumN,
             SEATS_MAX;
```

**Edit:**
To list all columns of you table you can use the following query

```
  SELECT 'FLIGHTS.' || column_name
    FROM user_tab_columns
   WHERE table_name = 'FLIGHTS'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

This should make your life a bit easier, then copy and paste

Comment: So there is no way I could easily say "list all columns from this table plus something else"? I have to explicitly name all the columns?

Comment: not really, you need to list them, I'll add a small query that can help you to have a list of all columns

Comment: what would be the answer for Oracle SQL please?

Comment: for which question? How to avoid listing all the columns in the group by?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a common mistake to sql beginners. please note that when you use group by clause on some columns (in your case SEATS_MAX), most databases don't allow you to add other columns in your select clause except aggregation on SEATS_MAX such as count(SEATS_MAX), max(SEATS_MAX) and so on.

This is because your data has been grouped by SEATS_MAX so the result set is based on each group. to a group of data that has a same SEATS_MAX value, the values of Flight table's columns (FLIGHTS.*) are not necessarily the same. Therefore, databases don't know which values to return.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT flights.*, seats_max-booked_seats
    FROM flights, (SELECT COUNT(*) booked_seats, flight_id 
                     FROM bookings GROUP BY flight_id) book
    WHERE flights.flight_id = book.flight_id
```

Comment: that could work, but it depends on whether SEATS_MAX is in the FLIGHTS table or the PLANES table.  It's not clear from the OP's query, but I suspect it's in PLANES.